# Python Script to upload file to sharepoint

Tags: python, sharepoint, scripting, request, office365

I am using the below script to upload to sharepoint that I found here.
[How do I authorize a Python script to upload to SharePoint Online?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75836585/how-do-i-authorize-a-python-script-to-upload-to-sharepoint-online) . I created an app in azure correctly, I was able to get the site-id and drive-id but whenever I run the script I keep getting a

```
requests.exceptions.connectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An Existing connection was focibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))
```

```
import os
import requests

# Azure AD app registration credentials
client_id = '376f340a-7b96-40c6-89fb-xxxxxxxxx'
client_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
tenant_id = '3f5c7a77-062d-426c-8582-1xxxxxxxxxxx'

# SharePoint Online site URL and library name
site_id = '6d4d4ae7-be11-47d0-a9ad-xxxxxxxxxxx'
library_name = 'sridoclib'
drive_id = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

# Authenticate and get an access token
auth_url = f'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/token'
data = {
    'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
    'client_id': client_id,
    'client_secret': client_secret,
    'scope': 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'
}
response = requests.post(auth_url, data=data)
access_token = response.json()['access_token']

# Upload a file to the SharePoint document library using the Microsoft Graph API
file_path = 'C:/Users/sridevi/Desktop/test.txt' #local file path
file_name = 'test.txt'
folder_name = 'sri'
upload_url = f'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site_id}/drives/{drive_id}/items/root:/{folder_name}/{file_name}:/content'
headers = {
    'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}',
    'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
    'Content-Length': str(os.path.getsize(file_path))
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to upload a file to sharepoint site using python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23696705/how-to-upload-a-file-to-sharepoint-site-using-python-script)

Comment: Looks like this is using basic auth and the 365 library, I am just using a http put.

Answer (score 1):

I used the same script and I had a different problem, as I was unable to get the access token.

Perhaps it is a dumb question but the code you posted is just the example file and you have yours with the correct client_id (app_id), secret, tenant_id, etc?

Also,check the permissions for the app.
I managed to get it working by adding delegated and application permissions and then granting admin privileges to those who needed it:
[permissions image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9hEM.png)